# Tracking e-mail PHP with image still not working with Google Proxys

Tags: php, email, proxy, gmail

I used a transparent 1*1px on my emails for tracking opened mails.
But now with the google proxys, it doesn't work anymore.

Google replace any image src by an url of proxy and the server doesn't register the request correctly.

Anyone have an idea or have this problem ?

Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

Doing you own email tracking is a cat-and-mouse game that's often better to outsource to a third-party.

You might want to consider using an email service like mailjet (which offers 6,000 free emails a month) or sendGrid. Both provide email tracking and adapt their techniques as email service providers make changes like Google apparently just did.

Comment: Thank's for your answer but i don't want to use any service. If they succesfull track their email, we can too.

If I need to change after each modification of Google, I'll change but I don't know how :/